# Record Audio playing on the phone

Tags: android

What is the code  to record a song playing  on the phone? When i use the default code given on the android developers website and run it it crashes when i try to record a song playing on the phone,though it works fine when i try to record what i speak.Or is not possible not play a song and record it at the same time on android.

Answer (score 1):

[In this site](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) you will see all formats that Android supports;
I don't think it is possible to play a song, and record it if you use the standard Android library. You need a specific library.